# Which date is the earliest data for service.events().list of google-calendar-api?

Tags: python, google-api, google-calendar-api

I use service.events().list of google-calendar-api to get data,here is a part of my code:

```
  paraAgoDate='2019-01-01'
  UTCStartTime = 'T15:00:00.000Z'
  events_result = service.events().list(calendarId=calendarId,
                                                      orderBy='updated',
                                                      showHiddenInvitations=True,
                                                      showDeleted=True,
                                                      updatedMin = paraAgoDate + UTCStartTime 
                                                      ).execute()
```

But when I run my code,the error message is:

> googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/zhang_xueyuan%40c.tre-inc.com/events?orderBy=updated&showHiddenInvitations=true&showDeleted=true&updatedMin=2019-01-01T15%3A00%3A00.000Z&alt=json returned "The requested minimum modification time lies too far in the past.">

When I set `paraAgoDate='2019-01-02'`,there is no error.

Today is `'2019-01-31'`,I want to know which date is the earliest data for service.events().list of google-calendar-api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "calendar",
    "reason": "updatedMinTooLongAgo",
    "message": "The requested minimum modification time lies too far in the past.",
    "locationType": "parameter",
    "location": "updatedMin"
   }
  ],
  "code": 410,
  "message": "The requested minimum modification time lies too far in the past."
 }
}
```

Means that the date you have set is outside the allowance for the API.  updatedMin needs to be within the last thirty days.   This is undocumented but you can test it.  I have submitted a documentation bug to google

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/123651518